# KDE Neon pkcon update issue

Tags: kde-neon

Getting this error while trying to run the command pkcon update:

**Fatal error: WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: neon-desktop distro-release-notifier (due to neon-desktop) ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt (due to neon-desktop)** [image]

Also getting the same kind of error while trying to update through the discover system update:

**Can not remove system Package: WARNING: You are trying to remove the following essential packages: neon-desktop distro-release-notifier (due to neon-desktop) ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt (due to neon-desktop) Please report this issue to the packagers of your distribution**
[image]

Comment: Looks like dependency issue, what apt says?